# Executable file is replaced after execve when debug using gdb

Tags: c, linux, gdb

Sir, I have a simple code.

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  char *argv[2];

  argv[0] = "/usr/bin/env";
  argv[1] = NULL;

  execve("/usr/bin/env", argv, NULL);  
  return 0 ;
}
```

I build it with `gcc -O0 test.c` and try to use gdb to debug `a.out`. And I found that if I first type `r` to run it is starting program `a.out`, but when I type `r` again, the program is replaced by `/usr/bin/env`, I don't know whether it is a bug or feature.

Comment: Not your problem, but; don't use `NULL` in modern C++ - use [nullptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).

Comment: The 1st parameter for `execve()` should be the program's path. I am not so sure, what else you would expect here?

Comment: Maybe the `follow-fork-mode` or `follow-exec-mode` [described on the *Debugging Forks* documentation page](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html) could help.

Comment: I want to know why the executable file is replaced after `execve`?